# Call a function from javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, this

I have this code:

```
var foo = {
    x: 2,
    bar: function() {
        alert(this.x);
    }
};
```

Why does `foo.bar()` alert `2` while `[foo.bar][0]()` alerts `undefined`?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `[foo.bar][0].call(foo)` works.

Comment: when you call it like [foo.bar][0]() this actually points to the function itself

Comment: @KimitsuDesu Nope, `this` points to the array `[foo.bar]`, not the function itself.

Comment: my bad, got it wrong there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, technically `[foo.bar][0]` is equivalent to `foo.bar`, but at the point of calling the function `bar` has lost the "lexical binding" with the `foo` object, so when you call it, JavaScript actually executes the following:

```
foo.bar.call([foo.bar]);
```

Generally, this expression:

```
XXX.yyy(args)
```

Is interpreted as:

```
XXX.yyy.call(XXX, args);
```

*In this case `XXX` is `[foo.bar]` and `.yyy` is `[0]`.*

To fix it, you need to explicitly bind `foo` again:

```
[foo.bar][0].call(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

when you do `[foo.bar][0]()`, `this` in the `bar` is `[foo.bar]`, the array but not the object `foo`.

Just imaging that the method name is the number `0` (although that is wrong syntax).

```
([foo.bar]).0(); // you see, `this` became the array object: [foo.bar]
```

And `[foo.bar].x` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are invoking the function on the array object. The "this" keyword is equal to the array.

```
[foo.bar][0]();
```

In javascript the context in which a function is invoked can vary. The "this" keyword can have different values based on how it was invoked. If a function is invoked on an object (including arrays), the language will make "this" equal to the object that it was called on. On the other hand you can save the function of another object into another variable and invoke it. Like you did with this:

```
var test=[foo.bar][0];
test();`//here is alert "2"
```

and the context will be the window.

Research the call and apply methods in javascript. This will open you eyes on how flexible the "this" keyword is. This is a place of much confusion among many programmers coming from other languages, but once this principle is understood there is a lot of power that comes from it. JQuery for example uses "call" and "apply" to have the callbacks of events invoked in the context of the element that the event was fired on.

Answer (score 0):

That is because when you make `[foo.bar]` an array you are isolating it from the main object (foo) and in your function you alert `this.x` and in a newly created object [foo.bar] `this` is undefined